# Edit external object records from Heroku using salesforce connect

Tags: externalobjects, heroku-connect, salesforce-connect

We have an external database set up in Heroku using postgres. I would like to be able manage some data from the heroku postgres database in salesforce. I have configured salesforce connect with the OData 4.0 connection that is provided by Heroku, but I have some issues with it.

1. I want to view the records in lightning but salesforce only allows me to view the records in salesforce classic. From other youtube tutorials that I have seen, others have been able to view their external records in lightning but have not shown nor explained what they did.
2. I am unable to edit any of the records whether through classic or apex. I read this documentation that said it can be enabled but I do not have the options when setting up the external objects. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.platform_connect_considerations_writable_external_objects.htm&type=5. I have read/write access from heroku so I should be able to update the records I believe. I have a salesforce connect license and my account manager said it should not be a licensing permission issue.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is all of this supposed to come out of the box or do I have to set up my own process for updating external object records and viewing them in lightning?

Edit: Sorry I did not post what I am seeing earlier. I have no option for writable external objects which is why I am so confused
[image]

Comment: You have to either [sync the objects](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ext_data_sync_database.htm&type=5) or manually create them to have their schema be available (show up) in SF, then [create a custom object tab to surface the external object](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.platform_connect_considerations_compatibility.htm&type=5). It's worth noting that Salesforce Connect is not the same thing as Heroku Connect - see [tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/salesforce_heroku_integration)

Comment: @identigral I understand that they are both different. I already synced up and created the tabs for the objects and I can view them but only in classic. I want to know how I can edit the external object records.

Comment: Did you define them as [writeable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-external-objects-salesforce) ? Accessing external objects from console (the standard admin UI) in Lightning [isn't supported](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.platform_connect_considerations.htm&type=5)

Comment: Re: your latest edit. The error at the top of the page seems important. Why does it mention Dynamo? You should open a support case with Salesforce.

Comment: That error is shown when you try to create another connection with an already defined connection type. I already have an OData 4.0 connection established so it is warning me that I am at my limit of Odata 4.0 connections I can have. That should not be affecting my issues. Someone told me that salesforce may need to enable this feature manually for me so I contacted them. I will try to report what they tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I contacted support about this issue. They immediately responded with saying this was out of scope because we do not have the higher tier support plan and closed the case. I would not take no as an answer so I reopened the case and told them how I could not find any documentation in salesforce nor any help on the developer forum about my issue. I asked to escalate the issue and maybe speak to a manager. A couple hours later I received a response saying the support team is looking into my case and looking into activating the feature in my sandbox. A couple minutes after that I receive another email saying writable external objects are now activated in my sandbox. I checked my external data source connection and indeed I had that option now and I was now able to view external object records in lighting along with edit them in lightning.

TLDR: Asked support to activate feature and kept on pestering them when they refused to consider my case. Never give up!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be there are two basic setups due to which may be you are facing the above two issues:

Not able to view the records in lightning, below is the checkbox which can cause the issue:
[image]

Not able to edit the record on Salesforce, there is a **writable External object** field while creating the external object :
[image]

Let me know if the above resolves your issue!

Comment: I actually do not have the 'Writable External Objects' checkbox. I don't understand why and what I need for it to show up.

Comment: Would this feature be something that I would have to contact salesforce to enable in my org?

Comment: Actually, I did not find any documents that state that the [Writable External object](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.platform_connect_considerations_writable_external_objects.htm&type=5) checkbox can be hidden, I find it strange it doesn't appear in your org. Probably **Salesforce Support** would be the best bet here. Also, can try selecting **Type as Salesforce Connect: Cross Org**, for me Writable option is also coming through that. Let me know how you resolved the same

Comment: Salesforce support got back to me on this issue, and they said they can't help me because we do not have the proper help service level. They said we need to increase our support level so we can get developer support. I will ask to see maybe I can elevate the issue.

Comment: Cool, let me know what was the actual issue!